# How is $f(x) = x^3$, $F : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ an injective function?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

My Working:

$x_1\neq x_2 \implies f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$

Proof (contrapositive):

$f(x_1) = f(x_2)$

$x_1^3 = x_2^3$

$\sqrt[3]{x_1^3} = \sqrt{x_2^3}$

$\pm x_1 = \pm x_2$

$+x_1 \neq -x2$

So my answer was false this not a injective function. But the answer says that it is. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: It depends (as always) on the domain of $f$. It is injective over the reals, but not over the complex numbers.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point you missed is that there are no two cubic roots for a real number $x$, there is only one.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: An example: Let's solve $x^3=8$. You stated the two solutions for this equation are 2 and -2, where in fact it is only 2, because $(-2)^3=-8$. Does that help you?

Comment: @jame_smith What he means is that you should check your own answer. Is it really true that $(-x_1)^3=(x_1)^3$?

Comment: @user2520938 Thx so much for pointing that out :) Can't believe I didn't realise that.

Answer (score 0):

$\text{Method-1}$
$$f (x)=x^3$$
$$f (x_1)=f(x_2)$$
$$x_1^3=x_2^3$$
$$(x_1-x_2)(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_1x_2)=9$$
$$x_1=x_2 \space \text{or}\space \left(\frac {x_2}{x_1}\right)^2+\left(\frac {x_2}{x_1}\right)+1=0$$
$\text{Method-2}$

Just by differentiating 
$$f'(x)=3x^2 \ge 0 $$
Means function is increasing over its defined range ,so it injective function.

Just notice the function is odd so the graph is symmetric about x-axis .